# UV WAVELENGTHS ARCS

Tags: electromagnetism

Does a welding arc contain UV of all frequencies?
Would a 12v battery that was shorted out produce the same frequencies?
Suppose the discharge was purely orange rays or sparks what would that say about the UV light emitted?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m researching the composition of electrical discharges and arcs. What UV light frequencies are produced when an electric arc discharge or short  produces orange sparks from a 12v car battery?

Comment: Since your eyes don’t see UV, the fact that it sees sparks as orange has no bearing on whether there is UV produced or not. Welding does produce UV. Also, you can weld with a 12 bolt car battery if you really need to, although using two to get to 24V is better.

Comment: Thanks but presumably if there lots of white light as opposed to orange then there would be different UV frequencies?  I’ve read articles about arc eye but there’s no indication that when a welder gets flashed that any other structure of the eye is affected except the cornea I would have thought that there would be UV affecting both the cornea and the lens from such an event?

Answer (score 0):

A welding arc has a temperature of (typically) between 6500 and 10,000 degrees F, and a spectrum of a black body. That temperature represents less than an electron volt of energy (on average) per particle but at the high-energy tail of the spectrum it's enough to ionize iron and carbon atoms.  However, that's not enough to tear loose any of the deeper electrons from their orbitals which is what you'd need to produce X-rays when they deionize.

So, an arc will give you a very bad sunburn and thermal burns but no x-rays.

The orange and yellow sparks that fly off an arc that's melting steel are droplets of hot metal which burn in air to produce those colors.

Comment: Wasn't the question about UV? How is the X-ray relevant?

Comment: @nasu, I included that because beyond hard UV, you next get X-rays.